# Best way to implement a user logs

Tags: php

I want to implement a user activity logs system. My client wants to have a detailed logs on what data has been updated or deleted.

As of now I implemented a  user logs code but I needed to counter check every column if there has been any changes. It is quite tedious to make especially when there are more than 10 columns in a table.

Is there a better way to track the user activity logs?

> Table:
>       **USERCD** - The username of the user.
>       **LOGTYPE** - Whether it is UPDATE, DELETED, INSERTED OR LOGIN/LOGOUT.
>       **LOG** - This is where the details of the log will be inserted (ex. "The user updated the date from *Old Value* into *New Value*").
>       **LOGDATE** - Date of the log.
>       **LOGTIME** - Time of the log. 
>       **DATABASENAME** - What database the user accessed.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to make that in my table logs column is log id, username, logs(For every button he click that can change in my database it will automatically insert in my table logs),logs date_time and IP address.

Comment: Do you record the changes the user made like fore example old values and new value